# Native code crashing electron

Tags: electron

Electron version: 0.37.5.
Operating system: OSX 10.11.4

I'm using the X509 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/x509) module which works fine outside of electron. I suspect it could be due to the underlying dependance on openssl.

I followed the instructions here https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md to but the module is still crashing electron.

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run "npm install", run this
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

# On Windows if you have trouble, try:
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

Comment: You ever fix this? Try https://github.com/encharm/x509.js which I believe is a pure JS implementation.